# Increase pod disk-size in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I am trying to run a windows container on Azure kubernetes service, for same I need to increase **conatiner** disk-size which is currently 20Gb. As per Microsoft [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/container-storage), we can increase disk-size using storage-opt.

Could anyone tell how we can provide same option to container as not able to find same?

Comment: This depends on how you currently add storage to a given pod (assuming you mean a pod since it's inside a k8s cluster). EmptyDir? Mount Something from host? create a PV and mount it?

Answer (score 1):

> Increase pod disk-size in kubernetes.

Thanks to `Rick Rackow` for suggesting the same point.

You can use `Persistent Volumes` to manage storage in `Azure Kubernetes Service` and potentially increase disk space for your containers.

You can follow the below steps.

1. Create **Storage Class** by using below `yaml` code.

```yaml
    kind: StorageClass
    apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
    metadata:
      name: azuredisk-premium-retain
    provisioner: kubernetes.io/azure-disk
    reclaimPolicy: Retain
    volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
    allowVolumeExpansion: true
    parameters:
      storageaccounttype: Premium_LRS
      kind: Managed
```

I created a `Storage Class` called `azuredisk-premium-retain` that uses `Azure Managed Disks` with the `Premium_LRS` storage type.

```
Kubectl apply -f storage.yaml
```

2. **Create a Persistent Volume Claim**: Create a PVC that requests storage from the defined Storage Class.

```yaml
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
    metadata:
      name: azure-managed-disk-pvc
    spec:
      accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
      storageClassName: azuredisk-premium-retain
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 50Gi # Specify the required storage size here as per your requirement
```

Created `PVC` using below command.

```
 Kubectl apply -f pvc.yaml
```

3. Created `Pod` and mounted `PVC`

```yaml
    kind: Pod
    apiVersion: v1
    metadata:
      name: newpod
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: newpod
        image: nginx:latest
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/mnt/azure"
          name: volume
      volumes:
      - name: volume
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: azure-managed-disk-pvc
```

Created `Pod` using below command

```
 Kubectl apply -f pod.yaml
```

[image]

I created a `Pod` called `'newpod'` with a container that mounts the PVC at `/mnt/azure`. The volume is defined with the name `'volume',` and it references the `'pvc'` PVC you created earlier with a size of `50GB`.

If needed, you can increase the size of the PVC by updating the `storage` field in its YAML definition and then reapplying the configuration.

Reference :  [Container Storage Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/container-storage)